# Use xsl:templates to properly position elements with variable height

Tags: xslt, docbook

I have a DocBook source that looks a bit like

```
<book>
    <chapter>
        <sect1>
            <title>...</title>
            <para>...</para>
            <figure>...</figure>
            <para>...</para>
            <figure>...</figure>
            <para>...</para>
        </sect1>
        [...]
    </chapter>
</book>
```

Now I want to use an XSL transform to create an SVG document (I have some `<xsl:transform>`s doing the job) but as SVG does not flow automatically I need to set the y position of every `<paragraph>` and `<figure>` manually.

I have an (XSLT extension) way of determining the height of the final `<paragraph>`s and `<figure>`s, but how can I design my `<xsl:transform>`s to accumulate the height of all previous elements and set the y position of the next element accordingly?

A previous approach used the proprietary extensions `saxon:assign` to dynamically update a variable but I would like to resolve that dependency (especially as even the official documentations says "Using saxon:assign is cheating").

Let me know if you need any additional details (if you want every detail it basically boils down to [tutorial-svg.xsl](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape-docs/documentation/blob/0.92.x/tutorials/tutorial-svg.xsl) for the XSLT source and [tutorial-basic.xml](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape-docs/documentation/blob/0.92.x/tutorials/basic/tutorial-basic.xml) for a sample XML document to be transformed)

Comment: You can pass around parameters using `xsl:with-param` and having templates receive parameters with `xsl:param`. If you move to XSLT 2 then using tunnel parameters it might be easier, as you do not have to spell out parameter passing on each level.

Comment: While this would allow me to redefine a parameter in say template1, how would it allow me passing it to other templates? If I understand correctly the changed value would only be visible for templates called by template1 itself, but in my document the applied templates create siblings (i.e. do not call each other unless I misunderstood something fundamental).

Comment: Well, if you really need to compute the resulting height of each sibling and add them up then it looks like you need to do some sibling recursion and pass the parameter on each time you do an apply-templates to the following sibling element. If you need to both process the various nesting levels and sibling levels recursively I think it can indeed become quite tricky to keep track of values.

Comment: On the other hand the whole approach with an iteration of element result computation step by step in a single stylesheet seems to rely on a certain implementation, not sure if getting rid of saxon:assign makes the whole stuff portable.

Comment: Yes, as we need to call Inkscape to determine paragraph/figure heights it's probably not possible to achieve a fully portable result. I ended up porting `saxon:assign` along with the rest of the extensions we need to a custom parser implementation using python/lxml/libxslt/libxml2, so while it's still not portable in the actual sense it only relies on free software we already depend on anyway and should be moderately easy to maintain.